# Scrape or download datapoints behind a canvas

Tags: canvas, scrape

Im trying to obtain the cumulative return data from this website:

https://silvercross-im.com/en/investment-approach#performance

But the data is not available when 'inspecting' the page.

How would I go about obtaining the data anyway?

Kind regards,

Victor

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue easily. Take a minute to check - How to create [mcve] Thanks